# jQuery Sliding Nav in when Logo clicked

Tags: jquery

```
$('body .note-logo').click(function(){
    $('body').css({
        'margin-left':'-260px'
    });
    $('nav').css({
        'right':'0',
        'display':'block'
    });
});
$('body:not(.note-logo)').click(function(){
    $('body').css({
        'margin-left':'0'
    });
    $('nav').css({
        'right':'-260px',
        'display':'none'
    });
});
```

When `.note-logo` is clicked the `nav` will slide in and then when `body` is clicked the nav will slide out and the body will return to `margin-left:0`.

This only seems to fire `'body:not(.note-logo)'` so I can't exactly pull my `nav` in. Could someone help?

```
<nav>
            <div class="wrap">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Pellentesque">Pellentesque</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Aliquam">Aliquam</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nowhere" title="Morbi">Morbi</a></li>
                </ul><!-- /#nav  -->
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </nav><!-- /nav -->
        <div class="note-logo">
                  Logo
        </div>

        <section id="main"> 
            <div class="wrap">
                           Page content
            </div><!-- /.wrap -->
        </section><!-- /main -->
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @Phillip there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `stopPropagation` will fix your issue:

```
$('body .note-logo').click(function(e){ // Note the "e"

    e.stopPropagation();

    $('body').css({
        'margin-left':'-260px'
    });
    $('nav').css({
        'right':'0',
        'display':'block'
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sMgGJ/1/)

[JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the click from bubbling to the body when you click the logo.

This is called event propagation, [read more about it here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

```
$('.note-logo').click(function(e){ // <-- Note the 'e'

    e.stopPropagation(); // Don't click the 'body' behind the logo

    console.log('logo clicked!')
    return false; // For good measure, don't follow the link on the logo
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I ended up just using jQuery fade in and fade out. It gives a nice effect.

[How to stop page from scrolling for a mobile website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073672/how-to-stop-page-from-scrolling-for-a-mobile-website)